# Why is it not plausible that the criterion of identity determines the criterion of application for concrete objects?

Tags: identity

In the identity entry of the Standford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, section 4, third paragraph (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity/#CritIden), says the following (referring to concrete objects):

> In this case the criterion of identity for Fs is not stated as a relation between entities distinct from Fs and the criterion of identity cannot plausibly be thought of as determining the criterion of application.

Why is it not plausible?

Comment: We can apply abstract objects/concepts to individuals because the latter are distinct from them. But what would it even mean to "apply" concrete objects to anything? Generally, when identity of Fs is stated in terms not distinct from Fs there is nothing to "apply" Fs to.